# RabbitMQ Channel reuse (SimpleMessageContainer)

Tags: spring-rabbit

My spring boot application's is functionality it to listen to the messages on rabbitmq queue, do some processing in onMessage, and then publish the message on another rabbitmq queue. We are using spring-rabbit (1.7.2.RELEASE). We have configured listener using SimpleMessageListenerContainer.

My question is can i publish using he same channel on which I am reading he messages. Does spring-rabbit provides access to channel used by listener? so that same channel can be reused to publish?

Thanks,
Smita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use transactions (listener container), any operations performed by a transactional `RabbitTemplate` on the container thread will participate in the transaction and use the same channel.

If you are not using transactions, you can use a `ChannelAwareMessageListener` to access the channel the message was received on. See [Message Listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#_message_listener).

If you are using `@RabbitListener` you can add the `Channel` as a method parameter.

The current 1.7.x release is 1.7.9.

Comment: Yeah. I am using ChannelAwareMessageListener.